# What does 動詞た形 ＋ んじゃ mean?

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence when reading an essay：

> 「ぢちらしろ、そう何回も声をかけられ**たんじゃ**不快な気分になるなというほうが無理ではないか。」

I'm not sure what the significance of the んじゃ is where it is in the sentence.
My grasp of the sentence overall is something like:

> 'If which wherever you go, you get called out to by such a voice, isn't it impossible not to get uncomfortable?'

Is this along the right lines?

Source: そして生活が続く － 星野源　P22

Comment: ぢちらしろ???  静｛しず｝かにしろ *Be quiet!* ???

Answer (score 1):

> 声をかけられたんじゃ
>   if I was called out to

声をかけられた **の** では ー＞ 声をかけられた **ん** では －＞ 声をかけられたん **じゃ**

声をかけられたんじゃ is transformed from 声をかけられたのでは through 声かけられたんでは for convenience of the pronunciation.